# Adding an external/customized legend in ggplot2 multiple layer figure

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to add a customize legend to ggplot. I am using water colors plot from (http://www.nicebread.de/visually-weighted-watercolor-plots-new-variants-please-vote/). The code for vwReg is present in the website.

I am plotting 2 different data as

```
 mtcars$rand2 = rnorm(nrow(mtcars))
 mtcars$rand1 = rnorm(nrow(mtcars))
 pp1 = vwReg(rand1~wt, data=mtcars, spag=T, add=T, shade=F, spag.color="green")
 pp2 = vwReg(rand2~wt, data=mtcars, spag=T, add=T, shade=F, spag.color="red")
 ggplot2() + pp1 + pp2
```

However, it does not give any legend to rand1 and rand2. I tried to add a color asthestic to geom_path that creates spag (spagetti) plot.  However the plot is too thin and not visible. I am wondering if there is a way to add a customize-legend as a separate layer and tell it to be have 2 color red and green.
 [image]

I code for vwReg can be also downloaded from https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2706915/vwRegs.R

Comment: The example is not reproducible: `Error: could not find function "vwReg"`. You don't say from which package `vwReg` is coming.

Comment: @Pascal Sorry for not being clear. The code is present at https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2706915/vwRegs.R

Comment: i believe the vcd package has a (basic) grid-based version of legend, called grid.legend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also do this by changing the `vwReg` function a bit.  Right now, `color` is being set to `spag.color` not mapped.  If you change this line of the `vwReg` function:

```
gg.spag <-  geom_path(data=b2, aes(x=x, y=value, group=B), size=0.7, alpha=10/B, color=spag.color)
```

To something like this:

```
gg.spag <-  geom_path(data=b2, aes_q(x=quote(x), y=quote(value), group=quote(B), color=spag.color), size=0.7, alpha=10/B)
```

you will be able to get legends on your plot ([this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18395012/2461552) gives an example of mapping colors in this way).

You will have to do a little more work to make the legend look right.  First, you have to change `legend.position` in `theme` (right now `legend.position` is set to "none").  Once you allow legends, you'll see there is a continuous legend for `alpha` that you'll likely want to remove.  You can edit the color legend with`scale_color_manual`.

After editing the `vwReg` function as above, here is one way to make a figure with the legend with a color for each group.

```
ggplot() + 
    pp1 + pp2 + 
    theme(legend.position = "right") +
    scale_color_manual(name = "Number of Cylinders", values = c("green" = "green", "red" = "red"), 
                    labels = c("group1", "group2"), 
                    guide = guide_legend(override.aes = list(alpha = 1))) +
    scale_alpha_continuous(guide = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an ugly ( and completely non-elegant ) way out of this. Its combining  ggplot2 and legend with

```
 library(gridBase)
 plot.new()
 grid.newpage()
 pushViewport(viewport(layout = grid.layout(1, 1)))
 #Draw ggplot
 pushViewport(viewport(layout.pos.col = 1))
 print(ggplot2() + pp1 + pp2, newpage = FALSE)
 legend("topright", inset=.05, title="Number of Cylinders",
    c("rand1", "rand2"), fill=c("blue", "black") , horiz=TRUE)
 popViewport()
```