# Multiple legends for barplot fills in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I would like to create a stacked barplot with three different legends for different groupings of data.

For example, given the following dataframe:

```
Year <- as.factor(c(rep(1, 10), rep(2, 10), rep(3,10), rep(4,10), rep(5,10), rep(6,10)))
Category <- as.factor(c(rep("a", 15), rep("b", 10), rep("c", 10), rep("d",10), rep("e", 10), rep("f", 5)))
Region <- as.factor(c(rep("region1", 25), rep("region2", 20), rep("region3",15)))
data <- data.frame(Year, Category, Region)
```

I would like to plot a stacked barplot of the count of each Category by year.

```
ggplot() + geom_bar(data=data,aes(x=Year, fill=Category))
```

However, instead of having one legend for Category (like above) I would like to have three legends with Category subset by Region (ie the legend titled "region1" would show Categories "a" and "b"; the legend titled "region2" would show Categories "c" and "d"; and the legend titled "region3" would show Categories "e" and "f".

I have tried referring to these two threads:
[Legends for multiple fills in ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39185291/legends-for-multiple-fills-in-ggplot) and
[R: Custom Legend for Multiple Layer ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18394391/r-custom-legend-for-multiple-layer-ggplot).
However, I have had no luck applying them to a barplot. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sometimes do this sort of thing the "hard" way by mapping layers to additional aesthetics and then using `override.aes` to make the legends based on those aesthetics look the way you want them to.  It's not pretty.

Here is an example, where the `fill` legend is suppressed and legends are made for the three "region" subsets via `color`, `size`, and `alpha`.

First, get the *ggplot2* colors for 6 colors as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8197559/emulate-ggplot2-default-color-palette).

```
gg_color_hue = function(n) {
    hues = seq(15, 375, length = n + 1)
    hcl(h = hues, l = 65, c = 100)[1:n]
}

cols = gg_color_hue(6)
```

The three extraneous `geom_point` layers are included only to add the three legends to the plot; the actual points are suppressed by setting the `size` to 0 or `color` to NA.

Then comes the messy work in `guide_legend`, where each legend is changed to show the correct colors based on `cols` above.  Legends names are changed and the legend order is set.

```
ggplot(data = data, aes(x = Year) ) +
    geom_bar( aes(fill = Category), show.legend = FALSE ) +
    geom_point(data = subset(data, Category %in% c("a", "b") ),
               aes(color = Category), stat = "count", size = 0) +
    geom_point(data = subset(data, Category %in% c("c", "d") ),
               aes(size = Category), stat = "count", color = NA) +
    geom_point(data = subset(data, Category %in% c("e", "f") ),
               aes(alpha = Category), stat = "count", size = 0) +
    guides(color = guide_legend(title = "Region 1", order = 1, 
                                override.aes = list(shape = 15, size = 5, color = cols[1:2]) ),
           size = guide_legend(title = "Region 2", order = 2, 
                                override.aes = list(shape = 15, size = 5, color = cols[3:4]) ),
           alpha = guide_legend(title = "Region 3", order = 3, 
                                override.aes = list(shape = 15, size = 5, color = cols[5:6], alpha = 1) ) ) +
    theme(legend.key = element_rect(fill = "white") )
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What about something like that:

`ggplot() + geom_bar(data=data,aes(x=Year, fill=Category, color=Region)) + 
scale_fill_brewer(palette="Greens") + 
scale_color_manual(values = c("red", "black", "grey"))`

with scale_color_manual to be customized. You can get inspired by http://colorbrewer2.org/#type=sequential&scheme=BuGn&n=3