# How to create multiple legends for one aesthetic in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to do something similar as in panel B of this figure: https://ars.els-cdn.com/content/image/1-s2.0-S0002929721000938-gr3_lrg.jpg, where I use shape as a legend, and closed or open shape as a second legend.

I use the following example data

```
example_data <- data.frame(x=c(1,3,2,4,5,3,1,2,3,2),
                           y=c(3,5,7,9,1,3,4,7,8,9),
                           color=c('col1','col2','col3','col1','col2','col3','col1','col2','col1','col3'),
                           shape=c('triangle','circle','triangle','circle','triangle','circle','triangle','circle','triangle','circle'),
                           openclosed=c('open','open','open','open','open','closed','closed','closed','closed','closed'))
```

I manage to make a plot with the different shapes and open/closed dependent on the columns with

```
example_data$point_shape <- -1
example_data[example_data$shape=='triangle' & example_data$openclosed=='closed',]$point_shape <- 15
example_data[example_data$shape=='triangle' & example_data$openclosed=='open',]$point_shape <- 0
example_data[example_data$shape=='circle' & example_data$openclosed=='closed',]$point_shape <- 16
example_data[example_data$shape=='circle' & example_data$openclosed=='open',]$point_shape <- 1
example_data$point_shape <- as.character(example_data$point_shape)


ggplot(example_data, aes(x, y, colour=color, shape=point_shape))+
  geom_point()+
  scale_shape_manual(name='', breaks=unique(example_data$point_shape),
                     values=as.numeric(unique(example_data$point_shape)),
                     labels=c('Open square','Open circle',
                              'Closed circle','Closed square'))
```

[image: example]

I then tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/44725969/651779 to get two shape legends with

```
ggplot(example_data, aes(x, y, colour=color, shape=point_shape))+
  geom_point(show.legend=F)+
  geom_point(data = example_data[example_data$shape %in% c('triangle','circle'),], 
             size=0,alpha=0)+
  geom_point(data = example_data[example_data$openclosed %in% c('open','closed'),], 
             size=0, alpha=0)+
  scale_shape_manual(name='', breaks=unique(example_data$point_shape),
                     values=as.numeric(unique(example_data$point_shape)),
                     labels=c('Open square','Open circle',
                              'Closed circle','Closed square'))+
    guides(alpha = guide_legend(title = "Shape", order = 1, 
                                override.aes = list(shape = c(15,16), 
                                                    size = 5, color = "black",alpha=1)),
           size = guide_legend(title = "Open or closed", order = 2, 
                               override.aes = list(shape = c(16,1), 
                                                   size = 5, color = "black", alpha=1)))
```

[image: example 2]

But this didnd't add the two separate legends.

How can I change the legend to have 1 legend with a square/circle, and another legend with open/closed shape?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally like the ggnewscale package for this purpose. Not sure how exactly you wanted to arrange your legends - I am using different shapes rather than changing the fill.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggnewscale)
example_data <- data.frame(x=c(1,3,2,4,5,3,1,2,3,2),
                           y=c(3,5,7,9,1,3,4,7,8,9),
                           color=c('col1','col2','col3','col1','col2','col3','col1','col2','col1','col3'),
                           shape=c('triangle','circle','triangle','circle','triangle','circle','triangle','circle','triangle','circle'),
                           openclosed=c('open','open','open','open','open','closed','closed','closed','closed','closed'))


ggplot(mapping = aes(x, y))+
  geom_point(data = filter(example_data, shape == "circle"),
             aes(shape = openclosed)) +
  # it's important to give a different name to this scale than to the second scale
  # This can also be NULL
  scale_shape_manual("Circle", values = c(open = 1, closed = 16)) + 
  new_scale("shape") +
  geom_point(data = filter(example_data, shape == "triangle"),
             aes(shape = openclosed)) +
  scale_shape_manual("Triangle", values = c(open = 2, closed = 17))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-04-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Creative way to use the ggnewscale package! +1

Comment: @teunbrand thanks for the kind words, but I am not sure if deserved! Maybe it's just me thinking rather simplistically: As soon as I read "multiple legends for one aes", ggnewscale is the first thing that pops to my mind...

Comment: I always forget that you can use ggnewscale for aesthetics other than colour/fill :')

Answer (score 3):

This could be achieved by

1. mapping your variables `shape` on the `shape` aes and `openclosed` on the `fill` aes
2. Setting the shapes to 24 and 21 which allow for both color and fill
3. Adjusting the shape used for the `fill` guide

```r
library(ggplot2)

example_data <- data.frame(x=c(1,3,2,4,5,3,1,2,3,2),
                           y=c(3,5,7,9,1,3,4,7,8,9),
                           color=c('col1','col2','col3','col1','col2','col3','col1','col2','col1','col3'),
                           shape=c('triangle','circle','triangle','circle','triangle','circle','triangle','circle','triangle','circle'),
                           openclosed=c('open','open','open','open','open','closed','closed','closed','closed','closed'))

ggplot(example_data, aes(x, y, shape=shape))+
  geom_point(aes(fill = openclosed), color = "black") +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(24, 21)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c(open = "white", closed = "black")) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = 21)))
```

[image]