# Add custom legend for multi layer geom_smooth

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm smoothing out data points using `rms::rcs()` and `geom_smooth()` with different levels of smoothness as additional layers. I'd like to add a custom legend to the side that identifies each smoothness parameter, but I'm not sure exactly how to do this. I've tried this stackoverflow post: [R: Custom Legend for Multiple Layer ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18394391/r-custom-legend-for-multiple-layer-ggplot)
 with no luck.

How would I add a custom legend for each `geom_smooth()` using `linetype`?

Edit: I've updated the question to reflect a question around `linetype` and not `color`.

**Sample Code:**

```
library(rms)
  p1 <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(carat, price)) + 
  geom_smooth(method = "gam", formula = y ~ rms::rcs(x, 3), aes(linetype = "solid")) + 
  geom_smooth(method = "gam", formula = y ~ rms::rcs(x, 4), aes(linetype = "dashed")) + 
  geom_smooth(method = "gam", formula = y ~ rms::rcs(x, 5), aes(linetype = "dotdash")) +
  scale_colour_manual(name="Knots", values=c("solid", "dashed", "dotdash"), labels = c("3", "4", "5"))
```

**Plot:**

[image]

Comment: within each `geom_smooth` call, use `aes(color = X)`. e.g. `geom_smooth(method = "gam", formula = y ~ rms::rcs(x, 3), aes(color = "blue"))`

Comment: @bouncyball Thanks! Does the same apply if I wanted to use `linetype` also?

Comment: indeed it should

Comment: @bouncyball This is what I tried, but not working: `p1 <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(carat, price)) + 
  geom_smooth(method = "gam", formula = y ~ rms::rcs(x, 3), aes(linetype = "solid")) + 
  geom_smooth(method = "gam", formula = y ~ rms::rcs(x, 4), aes(linetype = "dashed")) + 
  geom_smooth(method = "gam", formula = y ~ rms::rcs(x, 5), aes(linetype = "dotdash")) +
  scale_colour_manual(name="Knots", values=c("solid", "dashed", "dotdash"), labels = c("3", "4", "5"))`

Comment: @Henrik I've updated question to reflect a new question using `linetype` instead of `color` since the duplicate link doesn't work with `linetype`

Comment: @Henrik nvm, `scale_linetype_manual()` is the appropriate method.  Thanks!