# Adding a legend to a ggplot()

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here is my code for a ggplot with multiple lines, however I wanted to add a legend which labelled the black line as "Close price" and the Blue as "RSI"

```
pRSI<-getSymbols("AAPL",src = "yahoo", from="2010-01-01",to="2014-02-01",auto.assign=F)
    df<-as.data.frame(pRSI)
    df<-df[complete.cases(df),]
    n<-nrow(df)
    df$RSI<-RSI(df[,4],n=14,wts=df[,6])
    ggplot()+
        geom_line(data=df,aes(y=RSI,x=c(1:n)),color="blue")+
        geom_line(data=df,aes(y=df[,4],x=c(1:n)),color="black")+
        xlab('Data Point')+
        ylab('Price')
```

Comment: Hi George, thanks for your question but could you please provide a full mimimum reproducible example so I (and others) can help? Thanks.

Comment: This question seems to be a duplicate, see following link for possible solutions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18394391/r-custom-legend-for-multiple-layer-ggplot

Comment: @M_Shimal `scale_colour_manual(name = 'Key',guide='legend',
                            values =c('blue'='blue','black'='black'), labels = c('Close Price','RSI'))` I have tried adding such code using thread above with no joy

Comment: @GeorgeLoftus the point is that you need to set the colour within the geometry aesthetic for ggplot to realise that a legend is needed.

Answer (score 0):

As **George Savva** mentioned in comments, ggplot puts in legend when colour goes inside the aesthetics.

You can get the legends using the code below.

```
pRSI<-getSymbols("AAPL",src = "yahoo", from="2010-01-01",to="2014-02-01",auto.assign=F)

df<-as.data.frame(pRSI)

df<-df[complete.cases(df),]
n<-nrow(df)
df$RSI<-RSI(df[,4],n=14,wts=df[,6])

df <- data.frame(RSI = rep(c("a","b","c"), 10),  = sample(c(1:50), 30))

ggplot()+
  geom_line(data=df,aes(y=RSI,x=c(1:n), color='blue - series'))+
  geom_line(data=df,aes(y=df[,4],x=c(1:n), color='black - series')) +
  scale_color_manual(name = "legend name", values = c("blue","black")) + 
  xlab('Data Point')+
  ylab('Price')
```

[image]